# how to update my ADT eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i have tried these steps:

1)eclipse->help->check for updates

after finishing showing no updates are available and showing "install cannot be completed "

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)

Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 21.0.1.201212060302 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 21.0.1.201212060302)

Only one of the following can be installed at once:

```
ADT XML Overlay 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58)

ADT XML Overlay 23.0.7.2120684 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.7.2120684)
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Android Development Tools 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)

To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.7.2120684]
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Android Development Tools 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58)

To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58]
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: ADT Package 21.0.1.201212060302 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 21.0.1.201212060302)

To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 21.0.1
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Android Developer Tools 21.0.1.201212060302 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 21.0.1.201212060302)

To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [21.0.1.201212060302]
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not use Eclipse for android developing, it's slow and lack of tools.
Also Eclipse support has ended by Google officially.

> With the release of Android Studio 2.2, the time has now come to say goodbye to the Eclipse Android Developer Tools. We have formally ended their support and development. There's never been a better time to switch to Android Studio and experience the improvements we've made to the Android development workflow.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Comment: F*** Google! I hate rewrite all workflow tools just because somebody changed his mind. For example, guess what you should do with ant scripts now?

Comment: @Tertium Google used Eclipse as a solution for a temporary period. They were developing Android Studio since 2012. They didn't changed their mind in a moment, they waited for years. If you have a little vision, you must have guessed this will be happen and you could slowly rewrite your scripts in this long period. We all were waited for it, and moved all projects an tools to Android studio with first release of the stable version(2014). Now we are in 2017, 2years passed. Try to use Android studio, You will never go back to Eclipse for developing Android. It has very advanced plugins and tools.

Comment: have tried several times! it's so slow and stupid, with so many bugs. it launches forever, every update of code makes it sick and loads processor. it uses too much memory. it was hate from first sight. it never works from a box! I installed this bunch of s*** today ~2gb!) and it refused to work showing several errors. the only reason I continue to read about this google's missbirth is that google laid its d*** upon us, those who helped android to grow. sorry for asterisks

Answer (score 2):

Stop using eclipse because Android Studio is  Developed for android development and with Android studio 2.2 Google has stop supporting eclipse.its a time you have to get use to with Android studio .